# Salesforce mobile sdk android error responses

Tags: force.com, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I use the SFDC mobile sdk for android, and i can't get the server error response details (only 400 error) which is limited,

```
public void sfInsert(final Context context, final RestClient client, final Activity launcherActivity) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, JSONException {
    RestRequest restRequest;
    String api = context.getResources().getString(R.string.api_version);
    if(Util.isNull(getId())) {
        restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(api, "DRX__c", ModelsUtils.getHashMap(this.asJSONObject(), doNotInsert));

    client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse response) {
            Util.toast("Insert success !");
                            // success case 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            /**
                            * HERE : rather than saying Insert error,i'd rather show the user the actual error happening in the server (validation rules, data privacy issues and so on.
                            */
            Util.toast("Insert error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

rather than saying Insert error,i'd rather show the user the actual error happening in the server (validation rules, data privacy issues and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out how, 
In the onError method add the following:

```
`@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    VolleyError volleyError = (VolleyError) e;
    NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;
    String json = new String(response.data);
    Log.d(json);
}`
```

The json string contains the Force.com server errors that you can display to the user.